# How can i run At-commadns with the ADB?

Tags: adb, usb-modem

I'm trying to communicate with the modem of my Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 over the ADB tool. My galaxy is rooted and is accessible through adb.

**I'm attempting to execute AT-commands over the adb-tool.**
I already tried a few AT-commands but the modem doesn't respond.

1. First of all I was running `cat /proc/tty/drivers` to get the right driver. my output:

```
root@m0:/ # cat /proc/tty/drivers
/dev/tty             /dev/tty        5       0 system:/dev/tty
/dev/console         /dev/console    5       1 system:console
/dev/ptmx            /dev/ptmx       5       2 system
/dev/vc/0            /dev/vc/0       4       0 system:vtmaster
rfcomm               /dev/rfcomm   216 0-255 serial
g_serial             /dev/ttyGS    250 0-3 serial
usbserial            /dev/ttyUSB   188 0-253 serial
s3c2410_serial       /dev/ttySAC   204 64-67 serial
serial               /dev/ttyS       4 64-67 serial
pty_slave            /dev/pts      136 0-1048575 pty:slave
pty_master           /dev/ptm      128 0-1048575 pty:master
unknown              /dev/tty        4 1-63 console
```

2. Consequently my driver address is `/dev/ttyGS0`, so I run the next command `echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/ttyGS0` but the modem doesn't respond and nothing happens:

```
root@m0:/ # echo -e "AT\r" > /dev/ttyGS0
root@m0:/ #
```

3. So I quit the tool and tried another command `service check phone`:

```
130|root@m0:/ # service check phone
Service phone: found
root@m0:/ #
```

It looks like it at least found a kind of a modem.

4. So, I Google a bit and I find a nice tool called microcom, which is included in busybox. I installed busybox and tried `busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/ttyGS0`, but the output was

```
root@m0:/ # busybox microcom -t 5000 /dev/ttyGS0
microcom: applet not found
1|root@m0:/ #
```

**I really hope you can help me to find my problem with my code or suggest some better commands.**

Comment: Use [this version of busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox), it will have microcom.